# How to make lock screen appear in monitor connected to laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, lock-screen

I currently have a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 installed, which I connect to a desk monitor. Every time I turn on the laptop, the lock screen only appears in the laptop's monitor and not my desk monitor. Is there a way to make it so that the lock screen only appears in my desk monitor while it is connected via HDMI?

After the lock screen everything else is fine, showing only on the desk monitor, as I already configured it in Settings->Devices.

Comment: I believe the lock screen appears on the monitor that has the focus. So click a window on the external monitor before you lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you can click on a Window on your Internal monitor or your External monitor to make it active. Then lock the screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. The password prompt will appear on whichever screen was active.

I rebooted in 18.04 and it works exactly the same way.

**NOTE:** Using Unity desktop environment in both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 LTS.